# CButtonColumn approve button executes PHP code without being clicked

Tags: php, gridview, yii, pdo, toggle

I have this code that would create and populate a table in Yii CGridView.

My problem is the function located in the `'approve'=>array('options'=>array('onclick'))` is being called for every refresh of the page even if the approve button isn't clicked.

I determined the mistake occurs by printing the value of the counter. The counter should only increment by 1 when approved is clicked not for every refresh of the page.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'registrants-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,

'columns'=>array(
    'user_id',
    'first_name',
    'middle_name',
    'last_name',
    'gender',
    'shirt_size',
    'receipt_number',
    'category',

    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{approve}, {update},{delete}',
        'buttons'=>array(

            'approve' => array(
                'label'=>'Approve',
                'options'=>array(
                    'onclick'=> $model->approveRegistrants($model->user_id, $model->category),
                    //ending approve-option array
                    ),
                    //ending approve-button array
                    ),

        //ending buttons array
        )
        //ending table-last-column array
        ),
//ending table-columns array
),

//ending zii.widgets.grid.CGridview     
));

?>
```

This is my function in my model.

```
public function approveRegistrants($user_id, $category){

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=secret; charset=utf8', 'Andy', '*****');
$getCounter = "SELECT registrants FROM counter order by registrants desc limit 1;";
$bool = false;
$show = '0';


do{
    $result = $db->query($getCounter);
    // $registrants = $db->query($getCounter);
    // $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $registrants = '1'; 

foreach ($result as $value){
    $registrants = $value['registrants'];
    echo 'hello'.$registrants.'</br>';
}

    // $registrants = $result['registrants'];
    // print_r($registrants);
    $max_registrants = '3400';
        if($max_registrants > $registrants){

        // pdo that will use $updateCounterByOne
        $updateCounterByOne = "UPDATE counter set registrants = registrants + 1 WHERE registrants = ". $registrants .";";
        $updateCounter = $db->prepare($updateCounterByOne);
        $updateCounter->execute();

        // return affected rows
        $returnAffectedRows = $updateCounter->rowCount();
        $bool = true;
        // break;
        }
        else{
        echo "No more slot Available";
        // break;
        }
}while($returnAffectedRows == '0');


if($bool = true){
    //sql syntax
    $selectApprovedUser = "SELECT user_id FROM registrants WHERE user_id = '". $user_id ."';";

    //pdo that will use $selectApprovedUser
    $updateApprovedUser = "UPDATE registrants set approved = 'YES' where user_id = ". $selectApprovedUser .";";
    $updateApproved = $db->prepare($updateApprovedUser);
    $updateApproved->execute();

    //pdo that will use $insertApprovedUser
    $insertApprovedUser = "INSERT INTO approved_registrants (user_id, category, approved_date) VALUES ('".$user_id."', '".$category."', 'curdate()');";
    $insertApproved = $db->prepare($insertApprovedUser);
    $insertApproved->execute();

    //execute trial
    $selectSomething = "SELECT registrants from counter where tandem = '0'";
    $doSelect = $db->prepare($selectSomething);
    $doSelect->execute();
    $hello = $doSelect->fetchAll();
    echo $hello[0]['registrants'];
}

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when approve button is clicked it will get the `user_id` and will do the PDO commands such as the update and insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see [`CButtonColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail), it states that `'options'` takes in key-value pairs for the HTML tag attributes. Therefore, you should not place PHP code here like what you did here, unless you want them executed immediately. This is wrong:

```
'options'=>array(
    'onclick'=> $model->approveRegistrants($model->user_id, $model->category),
),
```

What you want is a [`TbToggleColumn`](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView#gridcolumns) column from YiiBooster extension to approve/unapprove items:

```
array(
    'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbToggleColumn',
    'toggleAction' => 'user/toggleApproved',
    'name' => 'isApproved',
    'header' => 'Approved?'
),
```

You will also need a corresponding action in the controller. Don't forget to add `'toggleApproved'` to the controller filters. In this example, I have simply inverted the value of a single column, but you may do other stuff with this action.

```
public function actionToggleApproved($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    if(!is_null($model) && $model->hasAttribute('isApproved')) {
        $model->isApproved = $model->isApproved == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        $model->update(); // no validation
    }
}
```